# Mysql select query for selecting row by time period

Tags: mysql

I have a table employee where i want to select a row based on dates.

```
emp_id       validation_user        entry_date
-------------------------------------------------------
 10          mark                   2014-05-01 11:11:00
 10          ann                    2014-05-01 10:14:00
 10          marco                  2014-05-01 11:07:00
 10          mark                   2014-05-01 10:00:00
```

I would like to have the row when emp_id=10 and entry_date is less than 2014-05-01 11:11:00
This should return me only one row which is closest to 2014-05-01 11:11:00 not three rows

```
 emp_id       validation_user        entry_date
-------------------------------------------------------
 10                marco            2014-05-01 11:07:00
```

my select statement returns me 3 rows:

```
SELECT *    
FROM emp 
where entry_date < "2014-05-01 11:11:00"
```

Comment: `ORDER BY entry_Date DESC LIMIT 1` add this at the end of your query

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no row_number in MySQL, you can achieve this with limit and order by :

```
SELECT *    
FROM emp 
where entry_date < "2014-05-01 11:11:00"  
order by entry_date desc
limit 1
```

What we do here is order by entry_date to make sure the first row is really the first one we want, then we specify to limit the query to 1 value.

We specify to order in descending order as we want the highest value that is lower then the specified date.